# Why does std::remove_if create so many closures?

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

In this example, a `foo` instance does nothing but print whether it's copy- or move-constructed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct foo {
    foo()=default;
    foo(foo &&) { std::cout << "move constructed\n"; }
    foo(const foo &) { std::cout << "copy constructed\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    foo x;
    std::vector<int> v; // empty

    std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                   [x=std::move(x)](int i){ return false; });
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
move constructed
copy constructed
move constructed
move constructed
copy constructed
copy constructed
```

Questions:

- Why does `std::remove_if` create so many closures ?
- Even if multiple intermediate instances are necessary, one would expect they are all rvalues; so why are some of them copy-constructed ?

Compiler is gcc 8.1.1

Comment: Because it expects the function object to be free to copy?  There is rarely a reason not to pass `[&]` lambdas.

Comment: For comparison, clang 6.0.0 produces just a single one (expected) _"move constructed"_ (`-O2` for both clang and gcc).

Comment: MSVS 2018 also produces just a "move constructed" with both debug and release builds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we take a look at [the implementation of `std::remove_if` in gcc's libstdc++-v3](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d6733e793a09b4af7fd9935c0750db33d8b29464/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L860) we notice that the predicate is passed down the call chain (by value, at times) a few steps before reaching the lowermost `__find_if` function (used by `remove_if`).

Let's count the moves and copies:

1. `move constructed` when the predicate (including the captured `x`) is sent by value, but as a non-lvalue, to [`std::remove_if` entry point](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d6733e793a09b4af7fd9935c0750db33d8b29464/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L929)
2. `copy constructed` when passed on to the [`__gnu_cxx::__ops::__pred_iter(...)`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/c1a19623398be73ec61be375f8a9c920c099ca09/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/predefined_ops.h#L288) function, which in turn:
3. invokes the [`_GLIBCXX_MOVE` macro](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/c1a19623398be73ec61be375f8a9c920c099ca09/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/move.h#L158), thus the `move constructed`,
4. which moves the predicate over to the [`_Iter_pred` ctor](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/c1a19623398be73ec61be375f8a9c920c099ca09/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/predefined_ops.h#L277) which moves it (`move constructed`) into the `_M_pred` member.
5. The call from `std::remove_if` to [`std::__remove_if`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d6733e793a09b4af7fd9935c0750db33d8b29464/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L860) seems to be optimized, as the `_Iter_pred` is not an lvalue, I guess, but `__remove_if` in turn pass on the wrapped predicate, by value, to [`std::__find_if`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d6733e793a09b4af7fd9935c0750db33d8b29464/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L159), for another `copy constructed` invocation.
6. `std::__find_if`, in turn, forwards the wrapped predicate, by value, to [another `__find_if` overload](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d6733e793a09b4af7fd9935c0750db33d8b29464/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L101), which is finally the sink of this call chain, and the final `copy constructed`.

It can be interesting to compare with e.g. clang's *implementation* of `std::remove_if`, as clang (6.0.1) do not produce this move-copy chain for OP's `std::remove_if` example.  A quick glance shows that It seems as if [clang use traits on the predicates type](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/algorithm#L1999) to make sure to pass the predicate [as an lvalue reference](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/type_traits#L1126).

Both clang and gcc produce the same `move`/`copy` chains for the contrived example that follows, which shows a similar chain to gcc's implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct foo {
    foo() = default;
    foo(foo &&) { std::cout << "move constructed\n"; }
    foo(const foo &) { std::cout << "copy constructed\n"; }
};

template <typename Pred>
struct IterPred {
    Pred m_pred;
    explicit IterPred(Pred pred) : m_pred(std::move(pred)) {}
};

template <typename T>
inline IterPred<T> wrap_in_iterpred (T l) { 
    return IterPred<T>(std::move(l)); 
}

template <typename T>
void find_if_overload(T l) {
    (void)l;
}

template <typename T>
void find_if_entrypoint(T l) { 
    find_if_overload(l);
}

template <typename T>
void remove_if_entrypoint(T l) { 
    find_if_entrypoint(
        wrap_in_iterpred(l));
}

int main()
{
    foo x;
    remove_if_entrypoint([x=std::move(x)](int){ return false; });
}
```

Where both gcc (8.2.0) and clang (6.0.1) produces the following chain:

```
move constructed
copy constructed
move constructed
move constructed
copy constructed
```

Comment: Thank you..  interesting point about clang using traits to pass an lvalue ref...
For the example you added, if you compile with `-fno-elide-constructors`, you can see the full set of constructors as layed out in the source.